# Changing views, iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm got thrown into this big iOS project and i'm trying to figure out how to create a button that will be able to take the user, to the first view in the app, no matter where the user is.

In my head I should be able to do something like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self release];
```

Except that because I created my button, that tracks when to change view, in a `UIViewController`. Reason for this is:

1. Because I need the button on every page and it needs to look the same and have the same functions on every page.
2. I made it as a `UIViewController` and not UIView so I would have a `viewDidload` method to run setup code in (background color, text color and other stuff), again because this setup code needs to be the very same for every single page.

So my current problem with this is that if I run `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` on the `IBAction` for my button it removes my button since that is the `self.view`.

How can I be able to remove my button + the view the button is currently active on? And then load my start page that is already loaded ones.

UPDATE:

I got around 20-30 viewControllers.

To create the button i got a UIViewController with .m .h and .xib. I got a IBAction that responds to the touchUpInside were i run the code i showed in the start of the post. Then i use the viewDidLoad to set backgroundColor and textColor.

I place my button with this(this is the code i got on every single page to create by button):

The pages .h got ActionBarWithLogoff *actionBar;

The pages .m:

```
actionBar = [[ActionBarWithLogoff alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActionBarWithLogoff" bundle:nil];
[topBar addSubview:actionBar.view];
```

I'm calling [self.view removeFromSuperview]; from my button view and this is the reason why i won't work as expected. But i don't know what i need to replace it with. So i can from my buttons view controller remove other views.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit about your view controllers? How many view controllers do you have? How do you create and place that button in the view hierarchy? From which class are you calling `[self.view removeFromSuperview];`?

Comment: sure give me a moment and ill update with some more code

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom views and can add these views in ViewController view and then you can add/remove these custom views from View controller.

Comment: sorry but i can't see how that would make so I'm able to jump directly to my start page no matter where i am, in my app. Could you link/show some kind of example or explain it a bit further?

Answer (score 0):

First instead of adding the same button and same button action in every viewController, you can have a baseViewController with basic functionality(common to all viewControllers) like button and button action.

To load the viewController you have already shown once can be added as a rootViewController to navigationController. so at any point of flow using the following call.

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Could you show some kind of examples or explain a bit more. I'm totally new to iOS programming.

Comment: I have created a baseViewController. When I am trying to create a new View Controller give it subclass of `baseViewController` so that what ever functionality you have implemented in baseViewController will be available in other derived viewControllers also.

Comment: I can't find any docs on a baseviewController so I don't know how to create it

Comment: navigationController is like a STACK. when you are pushing or presenting another viewController it will be added to stack. That means you have the first viewController in the STACK at the bottom. you will get it by popping all the top stacks. The above statement will do the same. It will pop all the viewControllers except the first one which has been added as rootViewController.

Comment: baseViewController is the name for example I have used. this is called inheritance in object oriented programming...

Comment: Okey i think i understend now^^. So i'll need to make all of my 30 current ViewControllers inheritance from the same viewController etc called baseViewController? And then in this baseViewController i can do whatever i want and it will show on all viewControllers which inheritance from it? what code would i have to write in the views, that inheritance from my baseViewContoller, to show the elements thats on my baseViewContoller?

Comment: [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; seems to have no effect at all, no error and no view change. Any ideas?

Comment: all your viewController navigation done on same navigationController?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46227/discussion-between-mohan-and-user2408952)